# How do I open XML from link in razor?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, xmlhttprequest, webservices.nl

The task is quite simple, connect to another webservice using XML.
In the current pages (classic ASP) we use the following code:

```
zoekpcode=UCASE(Request.Querystring("zoekpcode")) <-- postal-code
zoeknr=Request.Querystring("zoeknr") <-- house-number

PC=Trim(Replace(zoekpcode," ",""))
NR=Trim(Replace(zoeknr," ",""))

strGetAddress="https://ws1.webservices.nl/rpc/get-simplexml/addressReeksPostcodeSearch/*~*/*~*/" & PC & NR

set xml = Server.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
xml.open "GET", strGetAddress , false
xml.send ""
strStatus = xml.Status
If Len(PC)>5 and Len(NR)>0 Then
    strRetval = Trim(xml.responseText)
End If

set xml = nothing

'Do something with the result string
```

One of the possible links could be: https://ws1.webservices.nl/rpc/get-simplexml/addressReeksPostcodeSearch/*~*/*~*/1097ZD49

Currently I'm looking for a way to do this in razor (C#), but all I seem to be able to find on Google is how to do it in JavaScript
I've tried (most combinations of) the following terms:

- razor
- xmlhttp
- comobject
- XML from url
- -javascript

Results were mostly about JavaScript or razorblades.
Based on other result (like in the search *comobjects in razor*) it seems that comobject aren't available in Razor.

I did find this question (**[How to use XML with WebMatrix razor (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13162518/how-to-use-xml-with-webmatrix-razor-c)**) on stackoverflow that seems to answer my question (partially), but is it also possible with a link to an external system (the mentioned web-service)?

Comment: Why does it use XMLHTTP in the first place and not just a simple HttpWebRequest? Surely that can be used in the embedded c# code in razor.

Comment: The reason that XMLHTTP is used is unclear to me.

A short search resulted in the knowledge that HttpWebRequest can be used in razor.

During testing I found that it results in a string.
Do you know if it is possible to use the string in the XmlDocument used in de linked question?

Comment: @Ralf Thank you for the push in the right direction. I'll post my own code as answer (but not mark it). If you would like to post your reply as answer I'll mark that one.

Comment: I'm not into this reputation hunt thing. So go on and show us what you have done.

Comment: I'll do that, but I have to wait until 8 hours after asking to post it as an answer... But here it is: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4420555/reply%20to%20stackoverflow.txt

Comment: @Ralf, The OP says this is classic ASP code. `XMLHTTP` is the COM-based mechanism for making HTTP requests in that technology. He cannot use `HttpWebRequest` in classic ASP.

Comment: @MikeBrind Ah good catch. I didn't got that its that ~classic~ and not plain ASP.Net.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have covered the consumption of Web Services in Razor web pages here: http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/209/Consuming-Feeds-And-Web-Services-In-Razor-Web-Pages.

If your web service is a SOAP one, you are best off using Visual Studio (the free Express editions is fine) to add a service reference and then work from there. Otherwise you can use Linq To XML to load the XML directly into an XDocument as in the ATOM example in the article:

```
var xml = XDoxument.Load("https://ws1.webservices.nl/rpc/get-simplexml/blah/blah");
```

Then use the System.Xml.Linq APIs to query the document.

Comment: I think this answer is excellent, because it's a lot easier and readable than mine. However this way gives an error saying that the XML is invalid. I'll mark this as an answer for other people to use.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of [Ralf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/777522/ralf) I came to the following code:

```
public static XmlDocument getaddress(string pcode, string number){
    string serverresponse = "";
    string getlocation = "https://ws1.webservices.nl/rpc/get-simplexml/addressReeksPostcodeSearch/*~*/*~*/" + Request.QueryString["PCODE"] + Request.QueryString["NR"];

    HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(getlocation);
    using (var r = req.GetResponse()) {
        using (var s = new StreamReader(r.GetResponseStream())) {
            serverresponse = s.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }

    XmlDocument loader = new XmlDocument();
    loader.LoadXml(serverresponse);
    return loader;
}

public static string getvalue(XmlDocument document, string node){
    string returnval = "";
    var results = document.SelectNodes(node);
    foreach(XmlNode aNode in results){
        returnval = returnval + "," + aNode.InnerText;
    }

    return returnval.Substring(1);
}
```